# Detect if mouse is over the entire form (included controls and aero border)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, onmouseover

I want to detect when the mouse cursor is over the form (over the form mean over the form and also over any control of the form and also over the aero border), then if the mouse is over the ENTIRE "Form" then change the background of a picturebox, and when the mouse is not over the form (the client + nonclient area) then change again the picture.

This is an example:

Mouse Over:

[image]

Mouse Leave:

[image]

I've tried to do it but no way... :

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
    Me.MouseHover, _
    PictureBox_Color.MouseHover, _
    Label_HEX.MouseHover, _
    Label_HEX_Value.MouseHover, _
    Label_HTML.MouseHover, _
    Label_HTML_Value.MouseHover, _
    Label_RGB.MouseHover, _
    Label_RGB_Value.MouseHover, _
    Label_CTRL_C.MouseHover, _
    Label_CTRL_S.MouseHover, _
    Label_CTRL_X.MouseHover, _
    RadioButton_HEX.MouseHover, _
    RadioButton_HTML.MouseHover, _
    RadioButton_RGB.MouseHover, _
    CheckBox_Copy_Syntax.MouseHover, _
    Panel1.MouseHover

    Timer1.Stop()
    Label_RGB_Value.Text = "0"
    Label_HEX_Value.Text = "0"
    Label_HTML_Value.Text = "0"
    PictureBox_Color.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Elektro
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
    Me.MouseLeave, _
    PictureBox_Color.MouseLeave, _
    Label_HEX.MouseLeave, _
    Label_HEX_Value.MouseLeave, _
    Label_HTML.MouseLeave, _
    Label_HTML_Value.MouseLeave, _
    Label_RGB.MouseLeave, _
    Label_RGB_Value.MouseLeave, _
    Label_CTRL_C.MouseLeave, _
    Label_CTRL_S.MouseLeave, _
    Label_CTRL_X.MouseLeave, _
    RadioButton_HEX.MouseLeave, _
    RadioButton_HTML.MouseLeave, _
    RadioButton_RGB.MouseLeave, _
    CheckBox_Copy_Syntax.MouseLeave, _
    Panel1.MouseLeave

    If ((MousePosition.X < Me.Location.X) Or MousePosition.X > (Me.Location.X + Me.Width)) _
    AndAlso ((MousePosition.Y < Me.Location.Y) Or MousePosition.Y > (Me.Location.Y + Me.Height)) Then
        Timer1.Start()
        PictureBox_Color.BackgroundImage = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use MouseEnter instead of MouseHover - set the picture on MouseEnter and clear it on MouseLeave

Comment: Thankyou so much, that solved the first part! but now I need to detect when mouse is over the aero border too.

Comment: See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/cf851eb4-52ec-4519-8d1c-eb52bc32eafd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a non selected image as the backing for the from and use mouse over on the image and if stretched all the way over the form that should work.
Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try This;

### Mouse Over

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseHover
    Button1.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
End Sub
```

### Mouse Leave

```
Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
```